# jQuery object and DOM- how can I use javascript to detect underlying element and append string to that

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to do a generic function that adds all the different object elements needed for SVGWeb to work properly. That's the easy part but how can I use javascript to detect underlying element and append string to that.

I would like to do this type of markup:

```
<div><script>svg('svgfile.svg')</script></div>
```

The point is that I don't want to specify the underlying element every time I want to put graphics on the page. It would make updating very annoying when you want to move graphics around and they are tied to specific element ids. My goal is to be able to use this like I could use img tag.

I have jQuery on the page so that could be used as well.

*edit* To clarify the question is that how do I pass the underlying element to javascript and append object string that svg() returns to the DOM? I tried $(this) but doesn't work.

Comment: not clear what the question and process being described are.

Comment: added some clarification.. is it any more clearer? :)

Comment: The easiest way to append the object code is document.write() ... I don't know what sort of brain damage I have this morning to not realize this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what i think you're trying to do: [svg example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmarc/BrKLR/1/)

Create your placeholder divs with appropriate classes and then use jquery to fill them in with the correct svg.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was trying to avoid. You are using classes to place the SVG. While that works for icons and such, it's not very good for one-time graphics. I prefer using disposable elements without specific ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on selectors do the job (you don't want to separate the logic from the actual content) and you want to write the script inline, you should use the `document.write` function.
[Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/BrKLR/2/) to an update version of ryanmarc's demo.

Hope it helps.